# Leer contenido binario de fichero desde cliente (html o javascript) y pasarlo al servidor (C# .net)

Tags: javascript, html, c#, html5, asp.net

Con html5 y/o javascript necesito seleccionar un fichero y pasar el contenido de este al servidor para tratarlo. El servidor es una maquina que usa C# con .net webforms.
Para recoger el valor usa una variable oculta en html y recogerlo luego con un Request.Form["key"].

En el lado del cliente tengo lo siguiente:

```
<script>
  function archivos(lista) {
     // Solo escojo el primer archivo de la lista
     var arch = new FileReader();
     document.getElementById("contenido").value = arch.readAsDataURL(lista[0]);
  }
</script>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server">
<span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
    Selecciona archivo <input type="file" multiple accept=".jpeg, .png" id="MyFiles" name="MyFiles" runat="server"  onchange="archivos(this.files);">
</span>
<input id="contenido" name="contenido" type="hidden" runat="server" />
</form>
```

En el lado del servidor para recoger el contenido del archivo:

```
byte[] contenido;
contenido = Convert.FromBase64String(Request.Form["contenido"]);
```

El problema que tengo es que al mirar la variable contenido en javascript me muestra de valor como "indefinida"

Nota aclaratoria: No puedo usar HttpPostedFile con Request.Files[] para obtener el fichero  porque al hacer submit este me sale como vacio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probablemente te salga como *indefinida* porque *readAsDataURL* es asíncrono, el resultado no está disponible hasta que termina de cargar el fichero.
Prueba a cambiar tu función para que leer el resultado enganchándote al evento *load*

```
function archivos(lista) {
    let arch = new FileReader();
    arch.addEventListener("load", function () {        
    document.getElementById("contenido").value =  arch.result;
    }, false);
    arch.readAsDataURL(lista[0]);
}
```

Aquí el enlace a la especificación https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#readAsDataURL

Y probablemente, para poder decodificarlo en el servidor, tendrás que eliminar primero la parte "data://" del inicio de la URL

Comment: Pongo entonces arch.readAsDataURL justo despues del let arch y antes del addEventListener?

Comment: No, después de haber registrado el manejador para el evento, he editado la respuesta.

Comment: ok, es lo correcto ! Gracias